# Searching an uploaded youtube video from my youtube video channel using c#

Tags: c#, video, youtube, youtube-channels

In Youtube,Please help me in searching the video which I uploaded in my youtube channel.. 
Here is the code I am trying..

```
namespace Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples
{

that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
  /// </summary>
  internal class Search
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: Search");
      Console.WriteLine("========================");

      try
      {
        new Search().Run().Wait();
      }
      catch (AggregateException ex)
      {
        foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
      var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
          ApiKey = "API KEY ",
          ApplicationName = "YouTubeUpload"
      });

      var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
      searchListRequest.Q = "T52cSiV4vV8"; // Replace with your search term.
      searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

      // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
      var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

      List<string> videos = new List<string>();
      List<string> channels = new List<string>();
      List<string> playlists = new List<string>();
      foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
      {
        switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
        {
          case "youtube#video":
            videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
            break;

          case "youtube#channel":
            channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
            break;

          case "youtube#playlist":
            playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
            break;
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
    }
  }
}
```

On running the above code I am getting a 'Bad Request 400' exception[Exception screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLNmo.png)

Am i missing something??

Answer (score 0):

You need set a field "ApiKey" with your APIkey, in [Google Console Developer](https://cloud.google.com/console/project)

First, enable the Youtube Data API to your project and then create credentials to get your APIKey.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12794378)

Comment: Oh, sorry. This is my first answer :).
The next time I will try to do it better.